# Cakephp loads old database config file

Tags: database, file, caching, cakephp, configuration

I developed a small cakephp website on local machine. When I upload to my host server, I realize that I must use their prefix for the database name and database user. So, I go and create new database name and new user. When I visit the site, it has this:

```
Warning (2): mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'old_name'@'localhost' (using password: YES) [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 552]
```

I am 100% sure, I already change the name to "new_name", it runs on my local machine, but I dont know why it still load the old name. I go to ftp, and download the database config file, it clearly stated that, the database user is "new_name", i dont understand why when I go to the site, it loads the old database config. I am new to cakephp, please help.

Comment: Can you post your entire database config code?

Answer (score 3):

try to clear the files from your app/tmp directory and tripple check the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it can take a while for files to become live. One host I use has a folder for upload and then they transfer to the live folder from there automatically. Could it be something like this?

You possibly need to specify an IP for the database instead of localhost. Often the database is hosted on a different server to the code.